# Adding file types to be recognized by Files.probeContentType(new File(".ttf").toPath());

Tags: java, oracle, file

Java has a build in content types detector, however, it misses some filetypes naturally.

```
Files.probeContentType(new File(".ttf").toPath());
```

It appears as if the implementation allows one to add more **FileTypeDetectors**  but I cannot figure out how.

Reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html

**So how can one add more files to be probed?**

On another note, do you consider Javas File.proveContentType to be effecient? Not only does one whas to create a Path object, but it also seems to iterate over these each time. I guess a caching mechanism would be required on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install your own `FileTypeDetector` you first create your own implementation:

```
public class MyFileTypeDetector extends java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector {
    public String probeContentType(Path path) throws IOException {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Then second you add a file `/META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector` to the jar which contains your implementation: Its content is the qualified class name of your implementation:

```
org.example.MyFileTypeDetector
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish they could have made it a bit easier, like maybe just use a hashmap and the extension instead. I guess this is is a bit more flexible.

Comment: @momo a FileTypeDetector could decide to look into the file, e.g. to detect some magic bytes, therefore the more general approach

Comment: Yes, I figured something like that.

Comment: there is also another way nowadays, whcih i just found out about: Annotate the implementation, with:  @ProviderFor(java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector.class) public class MyFileTypeDetector implements java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector {}

Maybe you can add that to your answer as well? :)

Comment: @momomo From which java release is this available?

Comment: @patrik You actually need to include https://github.com/rspilker/spi ... I stopped using it though. I think it does the services thing kind of automatically.

Comment: I think you can find it here using maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mangosdk.spi/spi/0.2.4